# difference between calling a function when it is pointed by a pointer and not pointed by a pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers, frame

may I know what are the differences in the way the function foo is being called here:

[image]

Comment: You may want to read this: [Why not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/12149471)

Comment: What do you mean by what are the differences? They're different things, and in this case they have the same result.

Comment: In the second one, the call is known at compile time. In the first, it is not known until run time (unless the compiler is very smart). Taking that further, the compiler is free to remove the functions `go()` and `foo()` completely in the examples. It would not change `"foo\n"` to `"main\n"` though.

Comment: In one case, the function is called directly, in the other case, it is called indirectly via a function pointer. In C, pointers do not necessarily have to point to data, they can also point to functions, and such function pointers can be used to call the function to which it is pointing.

Comment: A few CPU cycles.  As @ThomasJager points out, in the example you give you wind up in the same place. But they offer more flexibility / generality, [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort) is a good example of their use.

Comment: @PaulSanders Hi, could you explain little more by what you mean "you wind up in the same place"? what does it mean by the "same place" sorry for my stupidity, but I am new to this kind of stuff.

Comment: Read Thomas' comment.  The two pieces of code you have written achieve the same result by two different means,

Answer (score 1):

In (1), `main` calls `go` and passes the address of `foo` in the call. In (2), `main` calls `go` and does not pass any argument. (`foo` designates the function `foo`. However, when a function designator is used in an expression other than as the operand of `sizeof` or of `unary &`, it is automatically converted to a pointer to the function. So `go(foo)` is equivalent to `go(&foo)`.)

In (1), `go` takes a parameter that is a pointer to a function with unspecified parameters and return type `void`. In (2), `go` does not take any parameters.

In (1), `go` calls the function whose address it was passed, by using its parameter `proc`. In (2), `go` calls `foo`. (As above, although `foo` is used in `foo();`, it is automatically converted to an address, as if `(&foo)();` had been written. All function calls actually use the address of the function, even if function designator is used.)

Comment: My prof told me the one on the left is using a dynamic address. But whereas the one on the right is using a static address. Could you explain what is being dynamic on the left? is it the address of foo() being dynamic? or what is being dynamic here on the left? does it mean some the memory location of foo() changes from time to time? but foo()'s address is fixed from the beginning on the right? and it won't change at all? thanks

Comment: None of the above. Your prof means that you *could* have passed a pointer to a *different function* to the `go` on the left, and then it would call that function instead of `foo`. Not so with the `go` on the right.

Comment: @john_w: That is not an unreasonable use of “dynamic” and “static.” They are not frequently used that way in C, but, in general, “dynamic” refers to something that changes and “static” refers to something that stays the same. The code `foo();` that calls a function named `foo` always calls `foo`, but the code `proc();` that calls a function pointed to by `proc` can change; it calls whatever `proc` points to.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks, so the part being dynamic is the address that could passed as an argument to the go function? for example if foo() is located on 0x12345, then 0x12345 was passed into go() in the above. But say if I have something else say kool() being located on 0x3456, then if I do go(kool), 0x3456 will be passed to go() and kool() will be called instead. So pretty much any function could be called indirectly by go() whereas only foo() can be called by go() on the right hand side.